# WPF Multitouch simulation: Why TouchDevice.Id is 258?

Tags: wpf, multi-touch

I follow [these steps](http://www.wenjiun.my/2009/11/testing-windows-7-multi-touch-with.html) to download [Multi-Touch Vista](http://multitouchvista.codeplex.com/) and configure it to simulate finger touch using multiple mice.

It works well, now I have two red dots on screen, each controlled by a mouse.

And I then write a WPF application, which has a single window with a Canvas, and in the Canvas's TouchDown event handler, I log which finger (mouse) is touching the screen.

```
private void canvas_TouchDown(object sender, TouchEventArgs e)
{
    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(e.TouchDevice.Id);
}
```

But to my surprise, the `Id` is always 258, no matter which mouse I use - I expect it to be starting from 0 or 1, and the Id is different between 2 fingers (mice).

I am testing on Win7 32bit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I bought a touch monitor recently and I can test the same code on the new monitor. It turns out the Id property is only useful when multiple touches (fingers/stylus) are present, the first touch device will get assigned a "base Id", the second touch device will be assigned ("base Id "+ 1), and so on. On my new touch monitor, when I use all my ten fingers, they will be assigned Ids as 428, 429, 430,..., 437.

I guess the "base Id" can vary on different monitors.